# Angular : Navigating in auxiliary router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an app with auxiliary router and some nested routes in it.

If I remove navigation to my auxiliary router from my main routes it works fine.
If I do this from a nested route in my auxiliary router, nothing happens.

Here is an example of my routing :

```
{
    path: '',
    component: AppView,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeView,
        },
        {
            path: 'contact',
            component: ContactView
        },

        {
            path: 'quickview',
            component: QuickViewComponent,
            outlet: 'quickview',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'search',
                    component: SearchView
                },
                {
                    path: 'create',
                    component: CreateView
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I put something like this in HomeView `<a [routerLink]=['', {outlets: {quickview: ['quickview', 'search'}]>Search</a>`, SearchView is opened correctly.

If I want to close it from HomeView, I can put this and it works fine : `<a [routerLink]=['', {outlets: {quickview: null}}]>Close search</a>`.

But if I put this last piece of code in SearchView, nothing happens.
`<a [routerLink]=['', {outlets: {quickview: null}}]>Close search</a>`.

From what I understand, it seems routing in those nested routes don't know about this outlet 'quickview'. Is there really nothing I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to make it working by setting the relativeTo parameter to `route.root`.

It's not pretty but it works.

Here it goes :
`<a [routerLink]=['', {outlets: {primary: '', quickview: null}}] [relativeTo]="route.root">Close search</a>`